# Why does the maximum recursion depth differ from the limit in practice?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a (very) simple recursive function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

The maximum recursion depth is 3000, found by running:

```
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

But `factorial(2986)` is the largest number that successfully runs. What accounts for the difference?

Comment: Just a guess: the very file in which the `factorial` function is found may already be running at a non-zero stack depth. Your python environment may create some amount of stack in the process of running the file.

Comment: I guess you can change the recursion limit programmatically by calling `sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)`, although I don't think that's a good idea.